# Is it possible to add value in this way to Array?

Tags: javascript

```
value = a[0];
```

is it possible to do in this way in Java script?

Comment: No. That just assigns the value of the first element of `a` to `value`. `a[0] = value` works tho.

Comment: you mean a[0] = value; yes you can but it can replace value too. best is you use push fuction

Answer (score 2):

No. This is correct:

```
a[0] = value;
```

Because the Assignment operator has a right-to-left associativity.
Check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for operator precedence table.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No that will affect the value stored in first position `[0]` of array to the variable `value` :

```
a=[1,2];
value = a[0];
console.log(value); //will return 1
```

If you mean by value something like `number` or `string` :

```
11 = a[0];
"example" = a[0];
```

That will return following error mesage :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment(…)

So if you want to assign value to array you should use it like :

```
a[0] = value;
a[0] = 11;
a[0] = "example";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That will set the `value` variable to the first element in `a`. It will not set a new value to the array.